# How to stop a loop in a QPushButton pressed?

Tags: qt, serial-port, break, qpushbutton

I have a connection with Arduino. I need to send continuously a character to serial port to handle a motor series when I press a button. So I created a QPushButton and I want when it is pressed it send this character.
But when I need to create a loop I don't know how to break it. I tried this solution

```
...
Class .... {

private:
bool buttonPressed = false;

}

void MainWindow::on_pulsante1_pressed()
{
    buttonPressed = true;
    while (buttonPressed == true)
    {
    connect(ui->pulsante1,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(on_pulsante1_released()));
    qDebug() << "pressed";
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_pulsante1_released()
{
   buttonPressed = false;
   qDebug() << "released";

}
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't think Arduino and serial port are of any relevance here. the question boils down to how to break a loop with GUI button.  I don't see any loop in your code btw

Comment: Here there is a while condition that create that loop. I'd like when release button it can finish but program rest in loop and crashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a `QTimer` for that. Also you can define the frequency that the timer fires. For example:

```
#include <QTimer>

..
Class .... {

private:
QTimer timer;

}

void MainWindow::MainWindow(){
    // in your constructor
    connect(&timer, [this]{
        //
        // write to serial here
        //
    });

}

void MainWindow::on_pulsante1_pressed()
{
    qDebug() << "pressed";
    timer.start(1); // run this every 1 milisecond
}


void MainWindow::on_pulsante1_released()
{
   timer.stop();
   qDebug() << "released";

}

    }
```

Take a look to [QTimer documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html)